# Rails- Can I do a params.merge in a before_filter in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, before-filter

I want to add a parameter to the params hash on every request which is why I'm working at the ApplicationController level. I have something like the following which is not working.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :tagOn

    def tagOn  
      v = findValueToTagOn() #find somehow what will be the value to tag on. Is dynamic.
      Rails.logger.info("PARAMS BEFORE: #{params.inspect}")
      params.merge(:my_id => v.to_s)
      Rails.logger.info("PARAMS AFTER: #{params.inspect}")
    end
```

Right now both my before and after output is the same which tells me the merging to params is not working. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks.

Using Rails v 3.2.3

Comment: Why You are not using middleware for such tasks ?

Comment: I was using middleware initially. It is was easy to have params access in controller, not sure how to access/add to params in middleware. Second, the filtering code is meant to check what the path is to determine if user can have access to a page. In the middleware I inadvertently ended up filtering out all sorts of assets like images etc. I didn't want to go through the tedious process of trying to figure out how to avoid this behavior so it is easier if I did this in the before_filter and just do skip_before_filter on controller which had pages that were always allowed access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are one character off.

`params.merge!(:my_id => v.to_s)`

Comment: This worked. I also found that I could have just done `params[:my_id]= somevalue` . Duh!
For anyone interested the params.merge! works great if you need to add a hash of values for example:


    `my_hsh = {:my_id => "blah", :my_second_id => "blah2" }
    params.merge!(my_hsh)`